# Utility Bar removed but persist in package and deployment error

Tags: lightning, package

New Lightning app initially had utility bar but was removed. Using the manifest below to deploy app to another sandbox showing the following error:

> applications/ComplaintReviewUnit.app -- Error: In field: utilityBar - no FlexiPage named Complaint_Review_Unit_UtilityBar found

The package shows Complaint_Review_Unit_UtilityBar even though there is nothing set in the app utility settings. Is there another area I need to look at or just remove the UtilityBar line from the package and deploy it? Not what I like to do and would rather seek out where the utility bar is being picked up.

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>ComplaintReviewUnit</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>    
    <types>
        <members>Inquiry__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Inquiry__c-ComplaintReviewUnit</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>    
    <types>
        <members>Inquiry__c.ComplaintReviewUnit</members>
        <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <fullName>Complaint Review Unit Record Page</fullName>
        <types>
        <members>Complaint_Review_Unit_Record_Page</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>    
    <types>
    <members>Inquiry__c</members>
     <members>CRUTest__c</members>  
    <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>        
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Package (partial)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#0070D2</headerColor>
        <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>false</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
    </brand>
    <description>Tracking system....</description>
    <formFactors>Small</formFactors>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>true</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
    <isNavPersonalizationDisabled>true</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
    <label>Complaint Review Unit</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
.....
    <tabs>standard-Case</tabs>
    <tabs>Inquiry__c</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-report</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Dashboard</tabs>
    <tabs>CRUTest__c</tabs>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
    **<utilityBar>Complaint_Review_Unit_UtilityBar</utilityBar>**
</CustomApplication>
```

Comment: To be clear, do you really mean package, as in managed, unmanaged or unlocked package, or do you simply mean a selection of metadata items?

Comment: We manually build the manifest that builds the package. Then deploy.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you mean "a" package then, just the package.xml.

Comment: We create the manifest as needed which pulls the objects we deploy and zip up. Example manifest produces several objects here for which I’ve represented a partial of just the app object. This to show the resulting utility bar as a flexipage. But there is none in the app. Seems almost like once you create a uril bar then remove it stays. ?